# Javascript quiz control flow

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following 5 exercises? I got the other 95 Exercises right but these keep coming up as wrong on repl.

Can you tell me why these Exercises are wrong?
What is the error in the 5 exercises?

I was told an error in 1 exercise can throw error in the rest.

```js
// Exercise One: In this exercise you will create a variable called 'aboutMe'
// This variable should be assigned a new object
// In this object create three key:value pairs
// The keys should be: 'name', 'city', 'favoriteAnimal'
// The values should be strings associated with the keys. 
// return the variable 'aboutMe'

var aboutMe = {
  name: 'Brian',
  city: 'Columbus',
  favoriteAnimal: 'Dog'
};

return (aboutMe);
}

function exerciseTwo(animal) {
  // Exercise Two: In this exercise you will be given an object called 'animal'
  // Create a new variable called 'animalName'
  // Accessing the animal object, assign the 'animalName' variable to the 'latinName' key on the object.
  // return the animalName variable.
}

let animalName = {
  animalName: latinName
}
return (animalName)

function exerciseThree(userObject) {
  // Exercise Three: In this exercise you will be given an object called 'userObject'
  // The phonne number for this user is incorrect!
  // reassign the 'phoneNumber' key to the value: '(951)867-5309'
  // return the userObject

  userObject: phoneNumber.(951) 867 - 5309;
}

function exerciseFour(value) {
  let greaterThanFive = true;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
  // You will also be given a variable named: greaterThanFive
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the value is greater than 5. If it is, re-assign greaterThanFive the boolean true.
  if (value > 5) {
    value = greaterThanFive
  }

  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return greaterThanFive;
}

function exerciseFive(name) {
  let isSondra = false;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: name
  // You will also be given a variable named: isSondra
  // Using an 'if' statement check to see if the name is equal to the string 'Sondra'. If it is, re-assign isSondra the boolean true.
  if (name = isSondra) {
    return true
  } else {
    false
  }
  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return isSondra;
}
```

Comment: Why do you not have a `function exerciseOne() {`  you can return something from?

You cannot return something outside a function. Also why do you have  `return true` in one statement and just `false` in another? Lastly you cannot use dot notation for a string with spaces and you need `=` for assignment. you need to make the object look like the object in exercise one

Comment: `re-assign greaterThanFive the boolean true` means `greaterThanFive = true` - it should likely be false to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started....

In the first exercise, you have an extra closing curly brace after the `return`. Additionally, you can only use `return` within a function, which your code is not inside of. Instead, you'd have to have the variable logged to the console or shown as an `alert` or displayed in some other way.

```js
var aboutMe = {
  name:'Brian',
  city:'Columbus',
  favoriteAnimal:'Dog'
};

console.log(aboutMe);
```

Comment: It likely just needs a `function exerciseOne() {`

Comment: @mplungjan Perhaps, but since that wasn't included and given the simplicity of the assignment, I'm going with what what posted and not assuming anything.

Comment: `return the variable 'aboutMe'` and the other exercises  have `function exerciseXXXX`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I understand and see that. But as I said, given the simplicity of the tasks, I'm not going to assume anything. The OP did not post a function for the first exercise.